# SharePoint Online: Get List / Count of users who modified their profile properties

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, csom, sharepoint-online

We have a SharePoint Online environment, and i have a requirement to count the number of users who have updated their profile properties / profile pic. Is their any way to retrieve this information using CSOM .

Comment: Are you looking to use the managed CSOM or JS CSCOM?

Comment: I am planning to use JS CSOM, however a managed CSOM solution is also fine.